# Killing Vectors in The Alcubierre Metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, vectors, warp-drives

According to this [article](https://samuel-lereah.com/articles/Physics/warp-drives) about the Alcubierre metric, the metric can be transformed in a way that results in "spherical symmetry" about the x-axis. I have to assume they meant to say cylindrical instead of spherical here. But even without transforming to $r=x-vt$, I believe this is evident when transforming $y$ and $z$ to $p=\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$ and $\phi=arctan(\frac{z}{y})$, so I have to wonder if there is some other killing vector made apparent by transforming to $r$. Furthermore, if after transforming to $r$, I transform to a comoving time coordinate $n$ which eliminates the diagonal, would $g_{nn}dn$ be a killing vector?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.